# How can I use MongoDB's aggregate with $lookup to replace an attribute that holds an id with the whole document?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-lookup

I have two collections:

**user**:

```
{
    "_id" : "9efb42e5-514d-44bd-a4b8-6f74e6313ec2",
    "name" : "Haralt",
    "age" : 21,
    "bloodlineId" : "c59a2d02-f304-49a8-a52a-44018fc15fe6",
    "villageId" : "foovillage"
}
```

**bloodlines**:

```
{
    "_id" : "c59a2d02-f304-49a8-a52a-44018fc15fe6",
    "name" : "Tevla",
    "legacy" : 0
}
```

Now I'd like to do an aggregate to replace `user.bloodlineId` with the whole bloodline document.
This is what I tried to far:

```
db.getCollection('character').aggregate([
{
    "$match": { _id: "9efb42e5-514d-44bd-a4b8-6f74e6313ec2" }
},
{
    "$lookup": {
        from: "bloodline",
        localField: "bloodlineId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "bloodline"
    }
}])
```

The result is almost where I want it:

```
{
    "_id" : "9efb42e5-514d-44bd-a4b8-6f74e6313ec2",
    "name" : "Haralt",
    "age" : 21,
    "bloodlineId" : "c59a2d02-f304-49a8-a52a-44018fc15fe6",
    "villageId" : "foovillage",
    "bloodline" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "c59a2d02-f304-49a8-a52a-44018fc15fe6",
            "name" : "Tevla",
            "legacy" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Only **two** issues here. The first is that `bloodlineId` is still there and `bloodline` was just added to the result. I'd like to have `bloodline` replace the `bloodlineId` attribute.

The second problem is that `bloodline` is an array. I'd love to have it a single object.

Comment: Please try this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TmVU8OVzLd0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this pipeline might do the trick:

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      _id: "9efb42e5-514d-44bd-a4b8-6f74e6313ec2"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "bloodlines",
      localField: "bloodlineId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "bloodline"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "age": 1,
      "bloodlineId": {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$bloodline",
          0
        ]
      },
      "name": 1,
      "villageId": 1
    }
  }
]
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TmVU8OVzLd0)

If there's anything I'm missing, please let me know!